# ASP.NET Web API: how to post from a model bound to another model?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

For my first project using C# and asp.net CORE Web-API, I'm currently struggling on a particular issue. I cannot post an item whose model is bound to another.

So I have two models, Profession and ProfessionField, which respectively contain the following code.

Profession:

```
{
    public class Profession
    {
        public int ProfessionId { get; set; }
 
        public string? ProfessionName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ProfessionField:

```
{
    public class ProfessionField
    {
        public int ProfessionFieldId { get; set; }
 
        public string? ProfessionFieldName { get; set; }
 
        public Profession? Profession { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to post a ProfessionField item in order to get something like this as a result in JSON:

```
{
    "professionfieldid":"1",
    "professionfieldname":"Sports",
    "profession": [
        {
            "professionid":"1",
            "professionname:"journalist"
        }
     ]
}
```

As a request, I have this :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<ProfessionField>> PostProfessionField(ProfessionField professionField)
{
    _context.ProfessionField.Add(professionField);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetProfessionField", new { id = professionField.ProfessionFieldId }, professionField);
}
```

I tried executing these post request in different ways with httprepl but every time, the value of "profession" was null.

Examples of requests I tried:

`post -h Content-Type=application/json -c "{"professionfieldname":"Sport", "profession":"1"}"`

`post -h Content-Type=application/json -c "{"professionfieldname":"Sport", "profession":"1"}"`

`post -h Content-Type=application/json -c "{"professionfieldname":"Sport","profession": [{"professionid":"1","professionname":"journalist"}]}"`

For this last one, I get an error 400, bad request, with the following comment:"The JSON value could not be converted to name_of_my_project.Models.Profession".

Do you have any idea what would be the correct request syntax or how I could improve the binding of the two models to fix this?

Comment: Repeat your last test removing the '[' and ']' and you should be all set

Comment: @HasaniH yep it worked thanks ! Do you know why the profession attribute of the professionfield item remains null as in [this screenshot from the get method](https://imgur.com/a/Wie0ucH) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect the correct JSON structure should be:

```
{
    "professionfieldid":"1",
    "professionfieldname":"Sports",
    "profession": {
        "professionid":"1",
        "professionname:"journalist"
    }
}
```

Your first two attempts are wrong because they provide a simple string `"1"` for the `profession` property, when the model is clearly expecting a complex object. The last attempt supplies an array (i.e. a list) of objects (albeit in this case there's only one thing in the list), when the model expects a single object only.

Comment: Ok this seemed to work, thanks for the input ! May I ask some questions ? Like right now the request worked and was understood as I intented it to be but when I use the get method, the profession attribute of the possesionfield item remains null as you can see [there](https://imgur.com/a/Wie0ucH)

Is it normal ? Did I fail somewhere ?

Comment: Did you use the debugger inside the PostProfessionfield method and check that `professionField` contains all the data populated as you expect it to be, when the method runs? Also I don't know how your database is set up, nor your Get method, so I can't tell you whether any mistakes occurred there or not. Was the profession data written successfully to the database? You can check that separately of course.

Comment: No I will try all this !

I followed a tutorial from Microsoft where they don't use the database but I will look into it !

Thanks again !